# Filter Chain using original Http Request instead of the new Request created using RequestWrapper while redirecting the request to a new URL

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I have a Java Filter that intercepts the request and changes a header based on certain condition:

```
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final 
                HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, 
                IOException {
                    if (condition) {
                       MyRequestWrapper newRequest = new MyRequest(MyRequestWrapper);
                   chain.doFilter(newRequest, response);
                } else
                            chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

The RequestWrapper class simply replaces one header value and also keeps reference of original inputstream if it is available in original request.

After this, I have implementation of Jetty's AsyncProxyServlet as follows:

```
public class AdminProxyServlet extends AsyncProxyServlet implements Watcher {
        
        @Override
        protected String rewriteTarget(final HttpServletRequest request) {
            //change URL and return true;
        }
}
```

What I have observed is, the header that I have changed in request wrapper is correctly received in the rewriteTarget function. However, finally when the request gets redirected to the new URL in rewriteTarget function, it is the original request that is getting redirected instead of the wrapped request.
Any suggestions on this?

Comment: File an issue at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: The request is not "redirected" (that means another thing), it is proxied. Some headers are classified as "hop" headers and must not be proxied, but you don't say which header you modify. Please open an issue as suggested in the previous comment. In general, what you describe should work out of the box.